# Why were my two answers deleted?

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

I posted my first answer on [Why did Beethoven include "in the Lydian Mode" in the title of String Quartet, Op.132 - 3?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/63050/why-did-beethoven-include-in-the-lydian-mode-in-the-title-of-string-quartet-o/) and it was later removed by Community:

[image]

So then I posted a second answer, which was eventually removed as well regardless:

> Probably because Beethoven was interested on doing things new. Remember, he also composed "jazz" in his 32nd piano sonata.
>
> - Please pardon me for this. My previous answer was marked as spam.
>
> <sup>Deleted by Doktor Mayhem ♦</sup>
>
> <sup>Hi Maika Sakuranomiya - the previous answer was inappropriate. This post doesn't answer the question. Please read our tour and How to Answer pages to get a better understanding of how this site works. - Doktor Mayhem ♦</sup>

---

Why is my first post spam or offensive?  Also, how come my second post does not answer the question?

Comment: Personally I’m totally mystified by your first answer. It’s a bunch of random characters, right? What makes you think random characters constitute an answer? Imagine if my comment here said “**#9$]¥£}{[~§€£98#$&@**”. Would you consider that appropriate content?

Comment: @ToddWilcox It seems to be "Because Beethoven is a Lydian star" written in internet graffiti style, for unknown reasons.

Comment: @replete Thank you for the translation. I'd never guessed!

Comment: You're right, Replete!  Awesome!

Comment: The word is ***awful***, not awesome. This site is not a childrens playground.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one is not only nearly illegible gibberish, it's simply a one-sentence opinion. It doesn't add anything useful, for sure, and I'd consider it spam on the grounds that it's so useless and garbage text. In fact, visually it looks similar to other junk answers we've seen in the review queue.

I'll defer to User Doctor Mayhem's answer for the second one, but I'll say this: If you had asked that question, how satisfied would you be with your answer?

Other than that, there are plenty of examples of really well written answers on this site that one could use for inspiration. *When in doubt, write something longer* **(to a point, obviously)**. *Explanations are what the OP usually wants, not just "the answer is Dmaj7" or whatever.*

Comment: The first one is "Because Beethoven is a Lydian star" written in internet graffiti style, as Replete had pointed out.

Comment: @MaikaSakuranomiya Irrelevant, I'm afraid. If it's defaced in that manner, it's completely unreasonable to ask viewers to decipher it, and I know for a fact at least one user did miss the message. I must ask, was there any particular reason you wrote it in that manner?

Answer (score 7):

The first one is inappropriate, and you already know this - you have been told.

The second did not answer the question. As we have recommended many times before, please read highly voted posts, and all the help pages to see the sort of thing that is expected. Look at the top voted answer on that one to see how different it is from your post. Even if you had tried to answer, you may just have got down votes, but your post doesn't answer the question at all - so when I saw the flags on it, I agreed with them and deleted it.

Answer (score 4):

> Why is my first post spam or offensive?

To me, it's arguably (slightly) offensive because of the way it wastes real people's time to have to clear it up!

All SE sites are moderated by volunteers. These moderation actions are part of what makes SE sites a readable and useful resource for thousands of readers.

Taking an action that *inevitably* is going to lead to moderator intervention, and adds little or no other benefit to the site, is rather unfriendly.